# How to ensure that the views are within screen boundaries

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 3 relative layouts (lets call them viewgroups) and layed out like this

```
           VIEWGROUP 1
           VIEWGROUP 2
           VIEWGROUP 3
```

I want VIEWGROUP 1 and VIEWGROUP 3 to take the space they need to display their contents. Then whatever space left, is allocated to ViewGroup2 (and its contents will be scrollable). Currently I have a Root Relative layout that add each group with the  "layout_below" attribute in reference to the previous one.

The problem that when VIEWGROUP 2 (say its textview component) is large, then it pushes VIEWGROUP3 out of the screen.

How do you recommend fixing this? I know there is a "hardcoding" way of fixing by assigning specific layout height but I want to avoid hardcoding and apply "use whatever space left"

Thanks

Comment: This is generally a bad idea, what will happen in landscape mode, or a smaller device? 1 & 3 may leave only a very small area of free space for 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have two different issues.

**Issues 1:** Assigning extra space to 3rd view

**Solution:** Use `LinearLayout` as parent and apply `layout_weight` to 3rd child view

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"><!-- LinearLayout height must match_parent -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Issue 2:** First two layouts pushing 3rd off screen.

**Solution a:** Make sure first two layouts smaller (don't know the details may not be an option)

**Solution b:** Scroll entire screen (simplest solution IMO)

T do this you do not want to use `weight_sum` as posted above. Instead wrap everyting in a `ScrollView`

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"><!-- Important ScrollView height match paternt -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"><!-- Important child view height wrap content -->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**EDIT**
In response to your comment you can make the middle view only scroll. This will work but has a couple of potentail issues.

1. The middle view will not expand to fill the empty space.
2. If your top or bottom views get to large it will be hard to scroll.

   ```
   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   </RelativeLayout>

   <ScrollView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"><!-- height 0dp with layout_weight -->
       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"><!-- height wrap_content -->
       </RelativeLayout>

   </ScrollView>

   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   </RelativeLayout>
   ```

Or if your prefer to use RelativeLayouts

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"><!-- height match_parent -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_3"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_above="@id/layout_3"
        android:layout_below="@id/layout_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I wanted the extra space to go to Viewgroup2 not 3 so I assume the weight sum is meant to viewgroup 2. This will do the job but then the contents are truncated. I want viewgroup 2 be scrollable if contents exceed space provided. Making the the whole thing scrollable would work but wont solve the problem I have which is  I want view1 and 2 to be alwasy visible

Comment: Ah, sorry I misunderstood that, I updated my answer with a couple options for that.

Answer (score 1):

Anchor VIEWGROUP3 to the bottom of the screen and have VIEWGROUP2 be `layout_below` VIEWGROUP1 and `layout_above` VIEWGROUP3. To make it take up the remaining screen, set VIEWGROUP2's height to `match_parent` and the other views to `wrap_content`.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I will try it and report back. Do that ensure that viewgroup2 is scrollable if the contents are byond the extra space

Comment: You would need to make viewgroup2 a ScrollView to enable scrolling. The child of that ScrollView can have `wrap_content` for height to make it expand as necessary.